# How to convert access database to firebird format?

Tags: microsoft-access, firebird

Is there a way to directly convert an access database to fdb(firebird) format using microsoft access? If not what's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can establish an ODBC connection to the remote database... you can export the data to the other database server.  *Sometimes* you must do some of the conversion manually... as each database flavor implements data-types differently.  (you can usually get around this by creating a similar database structure on the other side... then export data to the existing tables.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you would need to re-create the database in Firebird.

Check the MS Access metadata, extract SQL statement to create the tables and convert these to Firebird format, create a new Firebird database and re-create the metadata.

Next, you can transfer the data.

Shameless-plug-mode: this all can be done using Database Workbench ( www.upscene.com ) -- it can convert the metadata for you, so you don't have to work out differences between datatypes and SQL syntax (via the Schema Migration tool) and it includes a DataPump to transfer data.